# Is the word "Mleccha" mentioned in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas

The controversial word "Mleccha" is used to denote foreigners and barbarians in Hindu scriptures. This word is present in most Puranas and Dharmasastras. Is this word also present in the Vedas?

Comment: Do you want to know the answer from core portion i.e. Samhitas or  from Upanishads and Brahmana portions also?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Both!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's present in the Vedas but not earlier than the Brāhmaṇas according to a paper *[The Foreigner As The Other In Early India](http://14.139.54.19:8080/jspui/handle/123456789/361)* by Aloka Parasher-Sen on this subject:

> There is evidence that the Indians of the Vedic period had contact with the people of foreign countries. During the reign of Darius (522-486 B.C.) the Persians ruled over the Indus valley region and the adjoining areas. The Persians, known as Pahlavas in later Sanskrit literature, are not designated as *mleccha* during this period, apparently because they did not interfere with the brāhmaṇical way of life. **Except for the evidence from a passage of the *Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa* regarding the concept of the *mleccha* or barbarian, there is no further example of the kind in any of the Vedic texts**. The Yavanas are mentioned by Pāṇini in one of his *sūtras* but not as *mlecchas*. In the *Gautama Dharmasūtra* Yavana is noted as a mixed caste but, again, not as a *mleccha*. The creation of the image of foreigners as *mleccha*, that is, barbarians, thus, cannot be attributed to the early authors of the brāhmaṇical texts.

Transliteration of the said verse in Śatapatha-brāhmaṇa, Kāṇḍa III, Adhyāya 2, Brāhmaṇa 1 (Mādhyandina recension) from [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/1_veda/2_bra/satapath/sb_03_u.htm):

> 3.2.1. [24]
>
> tatraitāmapi vācamūduḥ | upajijñāsyāṃ sa mlecastasmānna brāhmaṇo mlecedasuryā 
>   haiṣā vā natevaiṣa dviṣatāṃ sapatnānāmādatte vācaṃ te 'syāttavacasaḥ parābhavanti 
>   ya evametadveda

Translation by Julius Eggeling at [wisdomlib.org](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63185.html):

> 24. Such was the unintelligible speech which they then uttered,--and he (who speaks thus) is a **Mleccha** (barbarian). Hence let no Brahman speak barbarous language, since such is the speech of the Asuras. Thus alone he deprives his spiteful enemies of speech; and whosoever knows this, his enemies, being deprived of speech, are undone.

The same author also explains the context of these verses in another paper, [*Attitudes Towards The Mleccha In Early Northern India - up to c. A.D. 600*](http://14.139.54.19:8080/jspui/handle/123456789/284):

> *Mleccha* speech in the *Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa* is synonymous with that of the Asuras
>   and *he'lavo he'lava* is given as the only specimen of that speech. The reason given for
>   the utterance of such unintelligible words by the Asuras was their defeat at the hands
>   of the Devas. The latter, being more clever and powerful, took the possession of *vāc* 
>   by offering her an *anuṣṭubh* verse. The following passage instructs brāhmaṇas  to avoid
>   *mleccha* language because when it was used by the Asuras it destroyed them.
>
> Since the Asuras were not called *mlecchas* but uttered words that were spoken by
>   such people, there are three possibilities - that *mleccha* or barbarian speech could have
>   meant hostile or vulgar speech; or a foreign or alien language; or the mispronunciation
>   of proper speech, in this case Sanskrit. The last plausibility arises out of Sāyaṇācārya's
>   explanation of the specimen of *mleccha* speech *he'lavo he'lava*, which, he suggests,
>   stood for *he'rayo he'raya* meaning "O the (spiteful) enemies". Patañjali in the Mahābhāṣya, 
>   setting out to explain *te'surāḥ*, has given the variant reading *he'layo he'laya*
>   which was used by Sāyaṇa to explain his theory. The *mleccha* phrase *he'layo he'laya*,
>   Patañjali explained, was a corrupt expression (*apaśabda*) and this was not sanctioned 
>   by grammar. His main concern being the study of grammar, he too instructed
>   brāhmaṇas not to use *mleccha* words.
>
> The emphasis on the *mleccha's* failure to pronounce the sounds *r* and *y* indicates the possibility that the reference to *mleccha* speech in the *Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa* could have been to a Prakrit dialect...

Comment: Yes , it's quite possible that such references of mleccha speech could have been to Prakrit dialect. Or refering to Buddhist or Jainis.

Comment: where is vedas reference?

Comment: @ManojPilania Don't you see the mantra and its translation from the Shataptha Brahmana?  Besides Samhitas, Brahmanas, Aranyakas Upanishads are also associated with the Vedas. Samhitas are not the only Vedas. Only few consider like that. I think you are one of them.